# Not accepting user input eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I've been searching overflow questions and googling it for about half an hour and can't find an answer for this.
At first I thought it might be that I'm not closing my Scanner object. I added
 `inp.close();` 
after all my code,but still nothing.
I'm using Eclipse to create a simple Binary Search algorithm. 
My problem is that it is not keeping my input. And what's even weirder is that it only accepts "5".
After pressing enter it only creates more spaces. It doesn't move on to the rest of the program.
I've also tried entering more values under the "skipped" ones without any success.

[Here's some screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF9A4.png)

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: you can post image anywhere and link it here

Comment: What do you mean, "keeping your input"?  Scanner "scans" over the input, one character at a time.  Similarly, what do you mean "it only accepts `5`"?  As in, it only accepts integers (which is what `inp.nextInt()` is supposed to do) or that literally only `5` is seen by your program?

Comment: @dimo414 By keeping what I mean is that it doesn't "see" it.. jeez sorry for that!
It literally accepts only the integer value 5.

Comment: That's because you are using nextInt api which will accept only integer. Also "My problem is that it is not keeping my input." You should be saving the data either in list or if you know the length in advance store it in array and do sorting or searching on the saved data.

Comment: @almasshaikh that's not quite my problem.The table of values is ready. I want the program to take a value from the user and search the table for that value. But it's not "seeing" the value I input.

Comment: @PanosGr i'm sorry that i didn't see those images are enlargeable.now viewable

Comment: Thank you for expanding your question, but the code snippet you've provided simply doesn't do what you're describing.  If you can provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) we'll be able to run it ourselves and explain the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I have a theory - your Scanner code is working just fine, it's your *binary search* code that's broken.  Whatever it's doing works on an input of `5` but falls into an infinite loop for other inputs.

Consider breaking up your input parsing code from your binary searching code (e.g. do input parsing in `main()` and define a `binarySearch()` function that `main()` calls) so that you can test them separately.

Comment: Actually that's the answer. I figured it out yesterday after trying out the code from scratch.Sorry for your trouble and thank you for putting effort into it. I think it should be helpful for anyone else that might run into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`nextInt()` reads scans the next token of the input as an int.

If the input is not an int, then an `InputMismatchException` is thrown.

You can use `next()` to read the input, whatever its type is. And you can `hasNextInt()` to make sure the next input is an `int`:

```
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
if(inp.hasNext()) {
    if(inp.hasNextInt()) {
        int n = inp.nextInt();
        // do something with n
    } else {
        String s = inp.next();
        // do something with s
    }
}
```